# Find the nth occurrence of a pattern in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to extract the value in 2nd occurrence of `<spot>` and `<Points>` tags. I tried different approaches with sub string and pattern index functions with out success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<FSSTradeDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Markup>
        <Price>
            <PriceType>A</PriceType>
            <Wholesale>1.2772663500412138</Wholesale>
            <WholesaleRateComposition>
                <Rate>
                    <Terms>A</Terms>
                    <CurPair>GBP-USD</CurPair>
                    <Spot>1.61125</Spot>
                    <Points>157.95740000000168</Points>
                    <Forward>1.6270457400000002</Forward>
                </Rate>
                <Rate>
                    <Terms>A</Terms>
                    <CurPair>GBP-EUR</CurPair>
                    <Spot>1.2648663500412138</Spot>
                    <Points>124</Points>
                    <Forward>1.2772663500412138</Forward>
                </Rate>
                <Rate>
                    <Terms>A</Terms>
                    <CurPair>EUR-USD</CurPair>
                    <Spot>1.27385</Spot>
                    <Points>0</Points>
                    <Forward>1.27385</Forward>
                </Rate>
                <RateStates>
                    <ContractCounter>DEf</ContractCounter>
                    <ContractVia>Dff</ContractVia>
                    <CounterVia>DDf</CounterVia>
                </RateStates>
            </WholesaleRateComposition>
            <Markup>12</Markup>
            <Quote>1.27846635004121</Quote>
        </Price>
        <Profit>
            <Amount>1.53</Amount>
            <SpotRate>1.27385</SpotRate>
            <Terms>A</Terms>
            <NativeAmount>1.2000000000000455</NativeAmount>
            <NativeCurrency>EUR</NativeCurrency>
        </Profit>
    </Markup>
    <WholesaleRiskTransfer>
        <Transfer>No</Transfer>
    </WholesaleRiskTransfer>
</FSSTradeDetails>
```

This is the query I've tried:

```
SELECT 
   convert(DECIMAL(38, 8), 
           substring(DETAILS, CASE 
                                 WHEN PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS) + 6 = 6
                                 THEN 0
                                 ELSE PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS) + 6
                               END, 
   (PATINDEX('%</Spot>%', DETAILS) - (CASE 
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS) + 6 = 6
                            THEN 0
                        ELSE PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS) + 6
                        END
                    )
                ))) AS [Spot Rate]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Also, have you tried extracting the details by considering this XML data as String or have you tried parsing it with SQL Server's XML tools? Either way, it is recommended to show / post the query you have tried before asking the question.

Comment: I tried with the below query, but able to get first occurrence value. 

select convert(decimal(38,8), substring(DETAILS,case when PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS)+6 =6 then 0 else PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS)+6 end,
    (PATINDEX('%</Spot>%', DETAILS)-(case when PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS)+6 =6 then 0 else PATINDEX('%<Spot>%', DETAILS)+6 end)))) as [Spot Rate] 

I am using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: DETAILS is the column name where we have the provided string

Comment: Trying to process XML as strings tends to lead to *extremely* brittle solutions. There are plenty of tools/languages that allow you to work with XML *as* XML and I'd seriously recommend using those instead (either the XML facilities built into SQL Server or using another language/library like C#/.NET)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use XML methods for this task:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<FSSTradeDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Markup><Price><PriceType>A</PriceType><Wholesale>1.2772663500412138</Wholesale><WholesaleRateComposition><Rate><Terms>A</Terms>
<CurPair>GBP-USD</CurPair><Spot>1.61125</Spot><Points>157.95740000000168</Points><Forward>1.6270457400000002</Forward></Rate><Rate><Terms>A</Terms>
<CurPair>GBP-EUR</CurPair><Spot>1.2648663500412138</Spot><Points>124</Points><Forward>1.2772663500412138</Forward></Rate><Rate><Terms>A</Terms>
<CurPair>EUR-USD</CurPair><Spot>1.27385</Spot><Points>0</Points><Forward>1.27385</Forward></Rate><RateStates><ContractCounter>DEf</ContractCounter>
<ContractVia>Dff</ContractVia><CounterVia>DDf</CounterVia></RateStates></WholesaleRateComposition><Markup>12</Markup><Quote>1.27846635004121</Quote>
</Price><Profit><Amount>1.53</Amount><SpotRate>1.27385</SpotRate><Terms>A</Terms><NativeAmount>1.2000000000000455</NativeAmount>
<NativeCurrency>EUR</NativeCurrency></Profit></Markup><WholesaleRiskTransfer><Transfer>No</Transfer></WholesaleRiskTransfer></FSSTradeDetails>'

SELECT
      WholesaleRateComposition.value('Rate[2]/Spot[1]', 'decimal(38, 20)') AS SecondSpot
    , WholesaleRateComposition.value('Rate[2]/Points[1]', 'decimal(38, 20)') AS SecondPoints
FROM @xml.nodes('/FSSTradeDetails/Markup/Price/WholesaleRateComposition') AS Price(WholesaleRateComposition);
```

To get the nth occurrence, you'll need to use dynamic SQL since the ordinals must be static:

```
DECLARE @Occurance nvarchar(5) = '3';
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX) = 
'SELECT
      WholesaleRateComposition.value(''Rate[' + @Occurance + ']/Spot[1]'', ''decimal(38, 20)'') AS SecondSpot
    , WholesaleRateComposition.value(''Rate[' + @Occurance + ']/Points[1]'', ''decimal(38, 20)'') AS SecondPoints
FROM @xml.nodes(''/FSSTradeDetails/Markup/Price/WholesaleRateComposition'') AS Price(WholesaleRateComposition);'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@xml xml', @xml = @xml;
```